# Controlling the number of items on a page in Grails' scaffolding view

Tags: java, grails

Is there any built-in way to allow the user to control the number of items to show simultaneously in Grails' scaffolding view? If not, what is the best way (Grails conventions-wise) of doing this?

Since the parameter `max` (like `offset`) is passed in the URL when using the default pagination and changing it is enough to have various list sizes work, I began to wonder if there's some built in way to allow the user to control it through interface? Right now, I'm using a naive brute-force approach of something like this in the generated `index.gsp` view:

```
    <a href="index?max=10">10</a>
    <a href="index?max=20">20</a>
    <a href="index?max=50">50</a>
```

...but I reckon this surely isn't the Grail-ish way of doing this but I couldn't find anything about either a built-in or a cleaner custom (in case of lack of the former) approach. As for the version, I'm using Grails 3.3.8.

Comment: It would be useful to include the version of Grails you are using in your question. A solution for 2.X and 3.X may not be the same.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore - true! Thanks, added it in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shurely be more grails-ish ways to do it. But I think this comes close.

First use [grails install-templates](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) to install the Templates.
Then edit the newly generated index.gsp template and add

```
<g:if test="\${${propertyName}Count > 10}">
    <g:link action="index" params="\${params + [max:10]}">10</g:link>
    <g:link action="index" params="\${params + [max:20]}">20</g:link>
    <g:link action="index" params="\${params + [max:50]}">50</g:link>
</g:if>
```

somewhere, perhaps below the `g:paginate` tag.

Other relevant links:
[grails generate-views](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html)
[The link tag in the gsp docs](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/link.html)